# How to JOIN and GROUP correctly

Tags: sql-server-2012, group-by, duplicates, inner-join

I am having trouble understanding how to join three tables together without creating duplicate records.

I have my first query which uses table profile, and tabe instruments:

```
SELECT
  [p].[shopper_id]
, [pi].[instrument_id]
FROM
  [dbo].[profile] [p]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[profile_instruments] [pi]
ON  [pi].[PID] = [p].[PID]
WHERE
  [p].[date_created] > DATEADD(yy, -2, GETDATE())
  AND [p].[shopper_id] = '53D5444535434747A935E207C9EDD96A'
ORDER BY
  [p].[shopper_id];
```

This query gives me the results:

```
shopper_id  instrument_id
53D5444535434747A935E207C9EDD96A    35
53D5444535434747A935E207C9EDD96A    17
```

My second query uses table profile and table styles:

```
SELECT
  [p].[shopper_id]
, [ps].[style_id]
FROM
  [dbo].[profile] [p]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[profile_styles] [ps]
ON  [ps].[PID] = [p].[PID]
WHERE
  [p].[date_created] > DATEADD(yy, -2, GETDATE())
  AND [p].[shopper_id] = '53D5444535434747A935E207C9EDD96A'
ORDER BY
  [p].[shopper_id];
```

The results are:

```
shopper_id  style_id
53D5444535434747A935E207C9EDD96A    845
53D5444535434747A935E207C9EDD96A    291
```

When I combine the 3 tables profile, instruments and styles:

```
SELECT
    [p].[shopper_id]
  , [pi].[instrument_id]
  , [ps].[style_id]
FROM
    [dbo].[profile] [p]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[profile_instruments] [pi]
ON  [pi].[PID] = [p].[PID]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[profile_styles] [ps]
ON  [ps].[PID] = [p].[PID]
WHERE
    [p].[date_created] > DATEADD(yy, -2, GETDATE())
    AND [p].[shopper_id] = '53D5444535434747A935E207C9EDD96A'
ORDER BY
    [p].[shopper_id];
```

I get the results:

```
shopper_id  instrument_id   style_id
53D5444535434747A935E207C9EDD96A    35  845
53D5444535434747A935E207C9EDD96A    35  291
53D5444535434747A935E207C9EDD96A    17  845
53D5444535434747A935E207C9EDD96A    17  291
```

I am not using a group by yet because I am unsure how to apply it with the columns I have. I am also unsure if the duplicates are because of the type of join I am using, or because I am not using a group by.

At any rate, I would like to ask for some help to be able to figure out what modifications to my query I need to make in order to have an output that looks like:

```
shopper_id  instrument_id   style_id
53D5444535434747A935E207C9EDD96A    35  845
53D5444535434747A935E207C9EDD96A    17  291
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: How do we know instrument_ID 35 goes with style_ID 845 and not 291?  Simply put your missing an association which defines this relationship.  without it you get the 4 results you're seeing.  So on the last join you need a and PS.??? = PI.??? to denote which style ties to which instrument.  If it doesn't matter, you could assign a row number to each record and join on the row numbers but this assumes both tables have an equal number of records per shopper.

Comment: They are independent from each other. There is a relationship between profile and instrument and profile and style, but not between instrument and style.

Comment: So how do we know 35 goes to 845 instead of 291?  Again I don't see how you have an expected result of 2 records in this example. If it really doesn't matter than the row Number concept may work; but it assumes equal number of records in each table or you need to use outer joins when they don't contain an equal number of records per shopper.

Comment: You are correct, it does not matter if 35 goes to 845 or 291 the same for 17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe...

We assign a row number to each style and instrument for each PID. Then not only do we join by PID, we join by Row_number which guarantees when a pID has 2 instruments and two styles, we still only get 2 records; instead of 4.

A full outer join is used as I don't know if you want to see situations where 2 instruments exists but only 1 style or 2 styles exist but only 1 instrument.

```
SELECT [p].[shopper_id]
     , [pi].[instrument_id]
     , [ps].[style_id]
FROM [dbo].[profile] [p]
INNER JOIN (SELECT A.*, row_number() over (partition by PID order by instrument_ID) RN 
            FROM [dbo].[profile_instruments] A) [pi]
  ON  [pi].[PID] = [p].[PID]
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT A.*, Row_number() over (partition by PID order by style_ID) RN 
                 FROM [dbo].[profile_styles] A)  [ps]
  ON  [ps].[PID] = [p].[PID]
 AND [PI].[RN] = [PS].[RN]
WHERE [p].[date_created] > DATEADD(yy, -2, GETDATE())
  AND [p].[shopper_id] = '53D5444535434747A935E207C9EDD96A'
ORDER BY [p].[shopper_id];
```

We may be able to use a coalesce on the PI.RN or PS.RN or both if you are willing to accept that when styles and instruments have different counts that matching to a single value in either table is acceptable

Example:

```
PID STYLE_ID      PID Instrument_ID
1   A             1   Z
1   B

The above should return
1 A Z
1 B

But maybe you want
1 A Z
1 B Z
```

This may work if we change `AND [PI].[RN] = [PS].[RN]` to 
`AND coalesce([PI].[RN],1) = coalesce([PS].[RN],1)` but testing needs to occur.  As if one side is devoid of all records for a pid, you'd still get null on one table.

Comment: Hi xQbert, when I try to use your example, it throws a syntax error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near 'row_number'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'over'.

Comment: I was missing () after row_number on 2nd subquery. and a comma after the a.* in first query (thx SqlZim)

Comment: I should note if a style or instalment id is inserted or changed, the associations could change

Comment: It is very likeable that a profile user will insert, or modify his/ hers current preferences for instrument and styles, is there another method to work this around? Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Not that I can see. Since we don't have a relationship between instrument and style.  My comment was to make you aware that the person style and instrument will be dynamic based on the data. If the relationship has to be kept, you need a person instrument style table to keep that data. Person =profile in above

Answer (score 0):

Try making a natural join, would look similar to this:

```
SELECT
    [p].[shopper_id],
    [pi].[instrument_id],
    [ps].[style_id]
FROM
    [dbo].[profile] [p],
    [dbo].[profile_instruments] [pi],
    [dbo].[profile_styles] [ps]
WHERE
    [p].[date_created] > DATEADD(yy, -2, GETDATE())
    AND [p].[shopper_id] = '53D5444535434747A935E207C9EDD96A'
    AND [pi].[PID] = [p].[PID]
    AND [ps].[PID] = [p].[PID]
ORDER BY
    [p].[shopper_id];
```

Comment: 2 records in instruments * 2 records in styles for each profile yields 4 records.  I don't see how this gets around that.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: I thought `natural join` actually used the words `natural join` and `using` you defined what same named fields in both tables you wanted to join